# JOLT Transformation : Convert string to Boolean in JSON Array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to replace the string value with a boolean based on the condition. If the `IsCompleted` value is `Yes` then the output value should be `true` if It is `No` then the output value should be `false`.

**Input**

```json
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Sumit",
    "IsCompleted": "Yes"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Sumit",
    "IsCompleted": "No"
  }
]
```

**JOLT Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "IsCompleted": {
          "Yes": {
            "#true": "IsCompleted"
          },
          "No": {
            "#false": "IsCompleted"
          }
        },
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "IsCompleted": "=toBoolean"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```json
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Sumit",
    "IsCompleted": true
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Sumit",
    "IsCompleted": false
  }
]
```

**Actual Output**

```json
[
  {
    "Id": [1, 2]
  },
  {
    "Name": ["Sumit", "Sumit"]
  },
  {
    "IsCompleted": [true, false]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed your spec to the true thing that should be. So you can use the following JOLT spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "IsCompleted": {
          "Yes": {
            "#true": "[&3].&2"
          },
          "No": {
            "#false": "[&3].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "IsCompleted": "=toBoolean"
      }
    }
  }
]
```